# Simple statistical test of experimental data

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have some experimental data: pre- and post-treatment results for 24 subjects, 12 treatment and 12 control. I created the two groups by pairing subjects according to pre-test results and randomly assigning within each pair.

Now I'm trying to figure out how to test the significance of my treatment effect. I was planning to calculate the difference between pre- and post-scores for each subject, then do a paired-sample t test of treatment vs. control subjects.

Does this make sense? Any advice much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[Randomized assignment is usually preferable to any manual assignment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54450/whats-wrong-with-some-pseudo-randomization/). Since you already observed the pretreatment performance, you could have controlled for initial differences between groups later. Then again, given your small sample size, this kind of pairing might just be the lesser evil.

This aside, what you propose is some sort of [difference-in-differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_in_differences) estimator of the treatment effect. It makes perfect sense. For each subject $i$, you compute
$$Score_i(t=1)-Score_i(t=0),$$
and then you test for differences between groups. The t test has some normality assumption and I am not sure if that is fulfilled with just 24 data-points. Maybe the corresponding [paired Wilcoxon-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) is better suited, as it is nonparametric and requires no such assumption.

If you have other explanatory variables on your subjects (education, age,..), you can also think about running some regression and controlling for those as well. The wikipedia article describes how to do difference-in-differences with OLS.

By the way, if your pairing was perfect, i.e., both subjects of the pair have almost equal pre-treatment scores, then you can also just compare the treatment scores (and not the difference of treatment and pre-treatment scores), because any group difference must come from the treatment scores.

Comment: Thanks very much for this - I'll look into the paired Wilcoxon test